# Store a session in memory to be used with later commands (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, api

I'm writing quite some Powershell modules to be used with different kind of (rest) api's. The first thing that you need to do when connecting to an API is creating a session with authentication credentials.
Now my question is: is it possible to store this session variable somewhere in memory, so it can be used with later commands?

Here's an example of a script with the Gitlab API.
I create this function to create a session pscustomobject:

```
function New-GitlabSession {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([pscustomobject])]
    param
    (
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4",
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$GitlabToken
    )
    $Header = @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $GitLabToken"
    }
    return [pscustomobject]@{
        Url    = $Url
        Header = $Header
    }
}
```

So I create a new session variable with this function:

```
$Session = New-GitlabSession -GitlabToken 'your token'
```

When I want to check the Gitlab projects, I can write a function like this:

```
function Get-Project {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([pscustomobject])]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [pscustomobject]$Session
    )

    $AllProjectGroups = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $($Session.Header) -Method Get -Uri "$($Session.Url)/projects/?simple=true" -FollowRelLink
    $AllProjects = foreach ($AllProjectGroup in $AllProjectGroups) {
        $AllProjectGroup | Select-Object id, name, path_with_namespace, http_url_to_repo, permissions
    }
    return $AllProjects
}
```

So as you see, when calling this function, I need to provide the `$session` variable:

```
$Projects = Get-Project -Session $Session
```

Now my question is: how can I write a function, that doesn't need to explicitly ask for the session variable?

So just something like this:

```
New-GitlabSession -GitlabToken 'your token'
$Projects = Get-Project
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Why not just combine them? Guess you can also go about it doing: `$Session = New-GitlabSession` and you would only have to call on `Get-Project`. You can also have it save to a `$global:` variable and just have your `$sessions` be assigned that variable. I think you should also rename the function to something more suitable such as, `ConnectTo-GitLab`, or something like that.

Comment: To be more clear: I want to put the functions in a separate file or in a module, and call them from a PS prompt. So I first want to establish a session, and afterwards use other functions from shell and still be able to use the session variable. 
But Mathias advised to use the default parameters. I will definitely look into that tomorrow 

Answer (score 3):

You could assign the result of the call to `New-GitlabSession` to the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` automatic variable:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Get-Project:Session'] = New-GitlabSession -GitlabToken 'your token'
```

Now PowerShell will automatically provide the session object as the argument to `-Session` unless you specify another value:

```
# no -Session parameter argument passed, default will be used
Get-Project    
# explicit argument passed to -Session, default will be ignored
Get-Project -Session (New-GitlabSession -GitlabToken 'someothertoken')
```

Comment: very cool stuff!

Comment: Hello Mathias, I tried out your suggestion about the PSDefaultParameterValues.
This is a very interesting approach, that will work in some cases.
However, in my case, I store the session variable as a pscustomobject, and this seems to be translated to a string in PSDefaultParameterValues, which I cannot use furthermore. So I probably need to refactor the code to not store a pscustomobject, but use strings instead.
I will give you a vote for the solution :-)

Comment: @Tjerk what makes you think that? You can store any value in $PSDefaultParameterValues as far as I know, not just strings

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Because I tested it:

Comment: ```powershell
$PSDefaultParameterValues.'Get-Project:Session'.GetType()
```

Comment: ```powershell    
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Comment: So when I store a pscustomobject in $PSDefaultParameterValues, under the hood it seems to be transformed to a string...

Comment: @Tjerk You must be doing something else as well, I'm entirely unable to reproduce this behavior. `$PSDefaultParameterValues['Get-Project:Session'] = New-GitlabSession -GitlabToken 'ydaydayaydaosdj';$PSDefaultParameterValues['Get-Project:Session'].GetType()` gives me `[scriptblock]`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Indeed, you are completely right. I found a little bug in my code: I used a function to set multiple PSDefaultParameterValues, and in that function I declared the Session variable as a string instead of pscustomobject.
Thanks a lot for the great feedback!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the feedback of Mathias R. Jessen, I have transformed my code into this working example:

I have the following Functions:

```
function Set-DefaultParameters {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [pscustomobject]$Session
    )
    $PSDefaultParameterValues['Get-Project:Session'] = $Session
    # Put here more functions that you want to use with the session variable
}

function New-GitlabSession {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([pscustomobject])]
    param
    (
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Url = "https://git.arxus.eu/api/v4",
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$GitlabToken
    )
    $Header = @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $GitLabToken"
    }
    $NewSession =  [pscustomobject]@{
        Url    = $Url
        Header = $Header
    }
    Set-DefaultParameters -Session $NewSession
    return $NewSession
}


function Get-Project {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([pscustomobject])]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [pscustomobject]$Session
    )
    $AllProjectGroups = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $($Session.Header) -Method Get -Uri "$($Session.Url)/projects/?simple=true" -FollowRelLink
    $AllProjects = foreach ($AllProjectGroup in $AllProjectGroups) {
        $AllProjectGroup | Select-Object id, name, path_with_namespace, http_url_to_repo, permissions
    }
    return $AllProjects
}
```

With these functions, I can run the following commands in my shell:

```
New-GitlabSession -GitlabToken 'yourtoken'
$Projects = Get-Project
```